# How does Red Lucy react to women?

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I just beat the mission, "Bleed Me Dry," and Red Lucy had her little *When Harry Met Sally* moment. What I'm wondering is, does that outcome change if you are playing as a woman? As a man with the Confirmed Bachelor or Lady Killer perk? As a woman with the Cherchez La Femme or Black Widow perk?

Or does none of that matter, and she reacts the same way no matter what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The outcomes are the same: if you give her the eggs, she will sleep with you.

Having played as a female character (with Black Widow), I was a little dissapointed that the perk didn't give any additional dialog options. My guess is that they didn't want to focus on this too much for fear of a whole Hot Coffee debacle.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hot_Coffee_minigame_controversy